# How to use Windows Emacs as an SVN client?

Tags: windows, svn, emacs

I just installed svn client from tigris and from the command line I can do checkouts, commits merges etc.
But now I would like to use emacs for merging files or directories.
vc-merge only works when you're in a file. I can't get it to work on a directory.
There is also the command line utility and for that I would like to use the same emacs session I'm using for my (dos) shell.

From the documentation I found I need to set SVN_EDITOR to:
gnuclient, emacsclient but that doesnt work either (hitting 'e' after finding conflicts reports emacsclient/gnuclient is not recognized as external editor). Putting c:\programs\emacs-23.3\bin\runemacs.exe starts a whole new emacs frame, and it doesn't show me the nice diff screen with the two conflicting files, I remember seeing when working with cvs and emacs.

Comment: If you're talking about merging your local changes then you could use `git-svn` http://git.or.cz/course/svn.html as a command-line svn client and `magit` http://philjackson.github.com/magit/ as a git client for emacs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use the same OS as you do, but for the `SVN_EDITOR` part, I think what you want is `emacsclientw` and not `emacsclient`, take a look at the binaries in `c:\programs\emacs-23.3\bin\`. You also probably need an emacs started in server mode, the function is named `server-start`.